# Trying to deploy a ERC721 NFT to Goerli but Remix shows gas error

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, gas

I'm, following the tutorial here

https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-create-an-nft

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("MyNFT", "NFT") {}

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

But is showing this error below

[image]

Update:

[image]

Not sure why it shows infinite gas, and yes I have already imported ERC721 and used it as an Interface

Answer (score 0):

Check your wallet balance. If you have a balance, calculate the transaction fee and check whether you have more than that. If you don't have any balance, get from [Goerli Faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/)

Comment: I do not have enough eth balance, why is Goerli gas always so high? In particular to deploy this i need 1.8eth

Also, how does the error relates to me not having enough eth? I'm pretty sure thats not the case here

Comment: Yeah. Nowadays, even in test networks the gas fee is so high. And in the faucet also they are giving only 0.2 eths per day. So I asked my colleagues to send me an eth in goerli network. Then it worked perfectly. Better try this!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues nowadays with Goerli. Gas fees can be really high and the network may be a bit unstable.

Simply put, you should not use Goerli for testing contracts. Goerli network is [deprecated](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#goerli) and it will probably be removed around Q1 2024.

Use Sepolia instead for all contracts tests.